# Find a dense embedding from specific forcing poset to any countable forcing poset

Tags: set-theory, forcing

I tried to prove this in the Kunen's set theory:

> Let $P$ be a countable non-atomic partial order. Show that there is a dense embedding from $T = \{p\in\operatorname{Fn}(\omega,\omega) :\operatorname{dom} p\in\omega\}$

At first I tried as follows: Let $A_0$ be a maximal antichain in $P$. Since $P$ is non-atomic, $A_0$ is countable. I shall construct the function $i$ from $T$ to $P$. Let $\{q_k : k<\omega\}$ be an enumeration of $A_0$ then define $i(\{(0,k)\}) = q_k$.

Let assume that $i(p)$ with $\operatorname{dom} p = n$ is given. If $A=\{q_k : k<\omega\}$ is a countable maximal antichain lies below $i(p)$ then define $i(p\cup\{(n, k)\}) = q_k$. It gives the order-preserving function $i$ from $T$ to $P$.

However I realized that my attempt does not work in some cases. For example, above construction need not always work in the case 
$$P = T \cup \{p\in\operatorname{Fn}(\omega+\omega,\omega) : \omega\subset\operatorname{dom} p \in \omega+\omega\>\text{ and }\>\forall n<\omega :p(n)=0\}$$
because we can take each antichain appeared in the construction as subset of $T$. I don't know how to avoid such problem nor find an other proof of it.
 I would be appreciated any help.

Comment: Could you provide more explanation about how you are picking your initial maximal antichain $A_0$? The reason I am asking is because we can't take just any maximal antichain since it may be finite. For instance, if $\mathbb{1}\in\mathbb{P}$, then $\{\mathbb{1}\}$ is a maximal antichain, but we don't want $A_0$ to be $\{\mathbb{1}\}$. My guess is that you are starting with some countably infinite antichain $A$, and then extending it to get a maximal antichain and then calling it $A_0$. Is that the case?

Comment: In case anyone else gets as confused as I did, what Kunen means by atomless is what would otherwise be called atomless + separative. That is, an atom for Kunen is a condition which has no incompatible extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a small modification of your construction which explicitly ensures that the embedding we build is dense.

Let $P=\{p_n;n\in\omega\}$ be an enumeration of $P$. We build the embedding $i\colon T\to P$ level by level. At the start, we map the top condition of $T$ to the top condition of $P$.

To define $i$ on the nodes of length $1$ we let $A_\emptyset$ be an infinite maximal antichain in $P$ (such a thing exists because $P$ is atomless) such that some $p\in A_\emptyset$ is below $p_0$. We then enumerate $A_0$ and map the $k$-th node of length $1$ in $T$ to the $k$-th element of $A_\emptyset$.

Proceeding by induction, assume that we have defined $i(s)$ for every $s\in T$ of length at most $n$ and consider an $s\in T$ of length $n$. To define $i$ on the immediate successors of $s$ let $A_s$ be an infinite maximal antichain in $P$ below $i(s)$ such that, if $p_n$ is compatible with $i(s)$, some element of $A_s$ is below $p_n$. We then enumerate $A_s$ and map the successors of $s$ to the conditions in $A_s$.

It is now clear that the embedding $i$ is dense; the image of every level of $T$ is a maximal antichain in $P$, so any $p_n$ will be compatible with some condition in the image of the $n$-th level, which means that the image of some node on the $(n+1)$-st level will get below $p_n$.

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot that in the forcing chapter (VII), Kunen further assumes that all partial orders come equipped with a top element. Seems this condition is necessary to ensure we can get the embedding to also be dense.

Comment: @Sam Yes. For example, the $T$ above cannot densely embed into two disjoint copies of itself.